# Como faço para usar o hump.timer em um loop repeat no LOVE2D?

Tags: lua

Estou perguntando isso para fazer algo mover no LOVE2D quando uma tecla é pressionada.

Eu já tentei

```
repeat
    imgx = imgx + 1
    timer.after(0, function() end)
until not love.keyboard.isDown('left')
```

mas não funcionou. Por favor, me ajudem!

**Codigo inteiro:**

```
function love.load()
    timer = require 'hump.timer'
    face = love.graphics.newImage("face.png")
    imgx = 0
    imgy = 0
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 'left' then
        repeat
            imgx = imgx + 1
            timer.after(0, function() end)
        until not love.keyboard.isDown('left')
    end
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(face, imgx, imgy)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo não usar loop nativo para mudar a cordenada x da imagem. Eu chamo isso de trabalho síncrono. Enquanto esse loop executa, o programa ficará parado (porém a `imgx` ainda vai mudar).

(Se você futuramente acostumar à executar `timer#after` em loops sem yields para fazer alguma coisa vai acabar criando problemas.)

Eu não acho que o problema tenha haver com isso, mesmo assim.

Experimente usar [`Timer#every`](http://hump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timer.html#Timer.every) (p.s.: não sei se isso resolve o problema, pois não conheço bem LOVE2D):

```
function love.load()
    timer = require 'hump.timer'
    face = love.graphics.newImage 'face.png'
    imgx = 0
    imgy = 0
end

local function tick()
    imgx = imgx + 1;
    return love.keyboard.isDown 'left';
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 'left' then
        timer.every(.1, tick); -- atraso: 100 milisegundos
    end
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(face,imgx,imgy)
end
```

Comment: Não funcionou... Tentei usar `love.graphics.print(imgx,400,300)`,mas o valor era 0 e não mudava

Comment: @arthurgps2 Hm, vou ter que aprender LOVE2D então